# Filling in missing blanks by groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a list of players and the games in which they played. Some players did not participate in every game, and as such, I want to 'fill in the blanks' of those missing games.

**Player (p)**

```
  player game_id points
  <chr>    <int>  <int>
1 Bob          1      3
2 Bob          2     18
3 Bob          3     10
4 Andy         1     20
5 Andy         2      5
6 George       1      4
7 George       2     13
8 George       3      6
9 George       4      2
```

**Games (g)**

```
  game_id location
    <int> <chr>   
1       1 H       
2       2 A       
3       3 A       
4       4 H
```

I thought that a `full_join`, while expensive and lengthy with a large number of observations, would work, but it appears that it only does when filtering to a single player.

```
# doesn't work with all players
full_join(p, g, by = 'game_id')

  player game_id points location
  <chr>    <int>  <int> <chr>   
1 Bob          1      4 H       
2 Bob          2     10 A       
3 Bob          3     12 A       
4 Andy         1      7 H       
5 Andy         2     20 A       
6 George       1      2 H       
7 George       2     11 A       
8 George       3     17 A       
9 George       4      1 H  

# but *does* work with just one
full_join(p |> filter(player == 'Bob'), g, by = 'game_id')

  player game_id points location
  <chr>    <int>  <int> <chr>   
1 Bob          1      4 H       
2 Bob          2     10 A       
3 Bob          3     12 A       
4 NA           4     NA H
```

Ideally, I want something like this using the `tidyverse`.

```
   player game_id points
   <chr>    <int>  <int>
 1 Bob          1     17
 2 Bob          2      1
 3 Bob          3     16
 4 NA          NA     NA
 5 Andy         1     12
 6 Andy         2      4
 7 NA          NA     NA
 8 NA          NA     NA
 9 George       1      9
10 George       2      8
11 George       3     14
12 George       4     18
```

I know that `full_join` would be *very* timely with large amounts of data, but is there perhaps a way to `full_join` by each player, or is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps `complete(p, player, game_id = g$game_id) %>% left_join(g) %>% mutate(player = case_when(!is.na(points) ~player))`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
complete(p, player, game_id = g$game_id) %>% 
 left_join(g) %>%
  mutate(player = case_when(!is.na(points) ~player))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach might be to use `group_split` on `player`, and then `map_dfr` from `purrr` for your `full_join` on each `player`.

```
library(tidyverse)

p |>
  group_split(player) |>
  map_dfr(~full_join(.x, g, by = "game_id"))
```

Or with just `dplyr` and using `group_modify`, as suggested by @akrun, you can do:

```
p |> 
  group_by(player) |> 
  group_modify(~ .x |> 
                   full_join(g, by = "game_id"))
```

**Output**

```
   player game_id points location
   <chr>    <int>  <int> <chr>   
 1 Andy         1     20 H       
 2 Andy         2      5 A       
 3 NA           3     NA A       
 4 NA           4     NA H       
 5 Bob          1      3 H       
 6 Bob          2     18 A       
 7 Bob          3     10 A       
 8 NA           4     NA H       
 9 George       1      4 H       
10 George       2     13 A       
11 George       3      6 A       
12 George       4      2 H
```

Comment: You could use `group_modify` and use only dplyr `p %>% group_by(player) %>% group_modify(~ .x %>% full_join(g))`

Comment: This is a good start. Say, however, that players do not play every game in the `g` frame. Instead, let's assume that the `g` frame has a team (and season) column as does the `p` frame:

With this format, the `full_join` adds *all games*, regardless of yr. or team, but is there a way to filter the join for team and year?

Comment: @xTrevi The `full_join` above assumes you are joining by `game_id`...however, if you have `team` and `season` columns, you could join by those columns as well...something like `full_join(.x, g, by = c("game_id", "team", "season"))`...if you want, you can edit your original post and data with an example to clarify further, and I can update the answer accordingly...